# How to mirror actions from a object to another in real time?

Tags: objects, mirror, parent, groups

im having some trouble with trying to mirror my actions into another object. So basically imagine Cube 1 and Cube 2 side by side, what i want to do is to when i change any form our scale of the Cube 1 the  Cube 2 take this actions as well. Sorry for the newbie question, im new at blender !

Here is a print of the problem im facing.

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hello :). You can use linked duplicates for this: [Blender Manual - Duplicate Linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html)

Comment: Thanks man !!!! thats exactly what i wanted

Comment: No problem, welcome to Blender :)